# Make Visual Studio 2008 use 8.0 CRT Libraries?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, crt

is there a simple way to make Visual Studio 2008 use 8.0 CRT libraries in my c++ project? I really do not want to install Visual Studio 2005 just to do this. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I also have 2010 installed, it looks like the "Target Framework" property can be extended to target CRT 8.0. Anyone know how?

Comment: is that for native code?  Sounds suspiciously .Net-ty to me, ie. only for C++/CLI.

Comment: It will take you 10 times longer to figure out how to config VS9 to target, compile and DEBUG your code using VS8 redists than just installing VS8.

Comment: Phil, you can use Daffodil, found at http://daffodil.codeplex.com/ to target 2005 from VC2010

Answer (score 4):

> I really do not want to install Visual Studio 2005 just to do this

Well, that's going to be difficult, you won't have the CRT include files if you don't do this.  You need them, especially to get the correct manifest.  Another obstacle is that the directories to search is a global setting, Tools + Options.  You'd have to carefully set the directories in the project settings so the 2005 directories always get searched first.

Installing 2005 takes half an hour, tops.  Tough to beat as soon as you hit the first snag, which ought to be getting the manifest right.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend this, you are setting yourself up for a world of hurt (> the time taken to install VS2005 and reconstruct the project, imo).

Why do you need to do it?

Comment: I need to compile a dll using CRT 8.0, as compiling with 9.0 presents incompatibilities in an existing binary that interacts with it.